# Confusion in interpreting 32 bit integer in Big Endian and Little Endian Machines

Tags: c++, c, endianness

I am in process of rewriting code from Big Endian Machine to Little Endian machine.

Let's say there is a variable called `a`, which is a 32 bit integer which holds current timestamp(user request's current timestamp).

In Big Endian machine, right now the code is this way:

```
uint32 a = current_timestamp_of_user_request;
uint8 arr[3] = {0};
arr[0] = ((a >> (8 * 2)) & 0x000000FF); 
arr[1] = ((a >> (8 * 1)) & 0x000000FF);
arr[2] = ((a >> (8 * 0)) & 0x000000FF);
```

Now, when I am writing the same logic for little endian machine, can I use the same code(method a), or should I convert the code this way(let's call this method b)?

```
uint32 a = current_timestamp_of_user_request;
uint32 b = htonl(a);
uint8 arr[3] = {0};
arr[0] = ((b >> (8 * 2)) & 0x000000FF); 
arr[1] = ((b >> (8 * 1)) & 0x000000FF);
arr[2] = ((b >> (8 * 0)) & 0x000000FF);
```

I wrote this program to verify:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void main() {
    long int a = 3265973637;
    long int b = 0;
    int arr[3] = {0,0,0};

    arr[0] = ((a >> (8 * 2)) & 0x000000FF); 
    arr[1] = ((a >> (8 * 1)) & 0x000000FF);
    arr[2] = ((a >> (8 * 0)) & 0x000000FF);

    printf("arr[0] = %d\t arr[1] = %d\t arr[2] = %d\n", arr[0], arr[1],   arr[2]);

    b = htonl(a);

    arr[0] = ((b >> (8 * 2)) & 0x000000FF); 
    arr[1] = ((b >> (8 * 1)) & 0x000000FF);
    arr[2] = ((b >> (8 * 0)) & 0x000000FF);

    printf("After htonl:\n");
    printf("arr[0] = %d\t arr[1] = %d\t arr[2] = %d\n", arr[0], arr[1],   arr[2]);

}
```

Results:

```
Result with little endian machine:

bgl-srtg-lnx11: /scratch/nnandiga/test>./x86
arr[0] = 170     arr[1] = 205    arr[2] = 133
After htonl:
arr[0] = 205     arr[1] = 170    arr[2] = 194

Result with big endian machine:
arr[0] = 170     arr[1] = 205    arr[2] = 133
After htonl:
arr[0] = 170     arr[1] = 205    arr[2] = 133
```

Looks like without conversion to big endian order, the same logic(without `htonl()`) gives exact results in filling the array `arr`. Now, can you please answer should I use `htonl()` or not if I want the array to be the same in both little endian and big endian machines(little endian result should be exact as big endian result).

Comment: If the goal is to put the least significant byte of the timestamp in `arr[2]`, then the code should be identical on both machines. The shifting and masking operations in the code are not endian-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as originally written will do what you want on both big endian and little endian machines.

If for example the value of `a` is `0x00123456`, then `0x12` goes in `arr[0]`, `0x34` goes in `arr[1]`, and `0x56` goes in `arr[2]`.  This occurs regardless of what the endianness of the machine is.

When you use the `>>` and `&` operators, they operate on the **value** of the expression in question, not the **representation** of that value.

When you call `htonl`, you change the value to match a particular representation.  So on a little endian machine `htonl(0x00123456)` will result in the value `0x56341200`.  Then when you operate on that value you get different results.

Where endianness matters is when the representation of a number using multiple bytes is read or written as bytes, i.e. to disk, over a network, or to/from a byte buffer.

For example, if you do this:

```
uint32_t a = 0x12345678;
...
write(fd, &a, sizeof(a));
```

Then the four bytes that `a` consists of are written to the file descriptor (be it a file or a socket) one at a time.  A big endian machine will write `0x12`, `0x34`, `0x56`, `0x78` in that order while a little endian machine will write `0x78`, `0x56`, `0x34`, `0x12`.

If you want the bytes to be written in a consistent order then you would first call `a = htonl(a)` before calling `write`.  Then the bytes will always be written as `0x12`, `0x34`, `0x56`, `0x78`.

Because your code operates on the value and not the individual bytes of the value, you don't need to worry about endianness.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `htonl()`. On a big-endian machine this does nothing, it just returns the original value. On a little-endian machine it swaps the bytes appropriately. So by using this, you don't have to concern yourself with the endian-ness of the machine, you can use the same code after calling it.

Comment: It's the same for c++, hence I rolled back your 1st edit.

Comment: His code uses `printf()` rather than `cout`, so it looks like C. But you're right that the relevant part of the question is the same for most C dialects.

Comment: Though the solution is the same for c++.

Comment: But if you see the result, the same variable gives same result as that of big endian machine's result for arr[] for same logic without htonl(). That is why i am confused.

Comment: As a reminder, `htonl()` is not standard.  The conversion can take place in 4 statements.

Comment: @noobincoding On a bigendian machine, `htonl()` doesn't do anything, so you get the same result with or without it.

Comment: @Barmar i understood that on big endian machine, results with or without htonl() are same. But i am not comparing them. What I am comparing is arr[] in little endian and big endian machines. Let's say that timestamp value is passed down to these two machines by some external entity. Without using htonl() on little endian machine, is arr[] exactly same in both little endian and big endian machines?

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe the code that's setting `current_timestamp_of_user_request` is already adjusting it.